# .htaccess rewrite to produce clean url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently I set a rewrite rule like so, to produce clean and simple url's.

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/about$  about.php  [L]
```

But what i need to do is something a little different, the other way around. For example if a user clicks the following link

```
<a href="index.php?a=page&b=about">about</a>
```

They would go to the about page `/about`

Currently the about page resides at `index.php?a=about&b=user` and this can't be changed unfortunately. As you can see it does not look very nice in the browser address bar.

**EDITED**

I am using a pre-made script from [phpdolphin](http://phpdolphin.com/), which is working fine. But the url are all `index.php` based and i would like to clean them up

Currently the only code within the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule before your existing rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?a=([^&]+)&b=user[\s&] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=user [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks, I tried this and unfortunately it didn't work. I've updated my answer with my current .htaccess

Comment: Put this rule on top before any of your existing rules.

Comment: thanks, Shall i change the `about.php` to `index.php` as i do not have a `about.php` everything runs off of `index.php`

Comment: Oh ok I saw `RewriteRule ^/about$  about.php  [L]` in your code and thought you have `about.php`

Comment: I tried this, it seemed to work but it added the string to the end. My question had the link back to front, i've edited it now `index.php?a=page&b=about` I tried your code with it swapped around but had the same issue, i think it's very nearly there.

Comment: I added a new question. Your answer works perfectly and fixed the issue u had in this question. I have another issue when trying to add another rule to it so i opened a fresh question addressing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this RewriteRule to redirect the request when user hit `index.php?a=about&b=user`

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}         ^(.*)a=about(.*)$    [NC]
    RewriteRule ^index.php        /about [L,NC,R=301]
```

or you can use php `header()` function in index.php to redirect  the request:

```
if ($_REQUEST['a'] == about) {
    header('Location: /about');
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  i checked and it  works  ...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-+_%*?]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-+_%*?]+)/?$    index.php?a=$1&q=$2     [L]
```

Note: add additional signs between [] if necessary

OR This

```
RewriteRule    ^([^~]+)/([^~]+)/?$    index.php?a=$1&q=$2
```

I like to use this code  because  it's short and matches everything except for ~ which is very very rare to see in a url